# check isatty in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want my shell to detect if human behavior, then show the prompt.

So, assume the file name is test.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "x" != "${PS1:-x}" ] ;then
 read -p "remove test.log Yes/No" x
 [ "$x" = "n" ] && exit 1
fi
rm -f test.log
```

But, I found it can not work if I haven't set PS1.  Is there better method?

my test methods:

```
./test.bash                  # human interactive
./test.bash > /tmp/test.log  # stdout in batch mode
ls | ./test.bash             # stdin in batch mode
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

to elaborate, I would try

```
 if [ -t 0 ] ; then
    # this shell has a std-input, so we're not in batch mode 
   .....
 else
    # we're in batch mode

    ....
 fi
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your sample is suitable for **stdin** case, for **stdout**, we can use `if [ -t 1 ]`.

Comment: for best answer would be `if [ -t 0 ] && [ -t 1  ]`

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This seems like a good idea. Sometime less is more, sometime less is just less. So ... Is this a new paradigm in shell scripting that I'm not aware of, or your personal opinion? Good luck to all.

Comment: As an addendum, since the question explicitly mentions Bash, this is the preferred way: `[[ -t 0 ]]` (and/or 1, depending on whether you want to check if stdin and/or stdout is attached to a terminal) because `[[ ]]` is a Bash builtin command, while `[ ]` spawns an external process.

Comment: @DanielYCLin, `[` (aka `test`) has built-in "and" — `-a`

Answer (score 9):

From `help test`:

> ```
>  -t FD          True if FD is opened on a terminal.
> ```

Comment: thanks, your answer is correct, but the next answer is clearer.

Comment: @Daniel YC Lin, SO has re-arranged the answers, so I'm not sure what answer you are referring to, nothing is currently "after" this answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could make use of the `/usr/bin/tty` program:

```
if tty -s
then
    # ...
fi
```

I admit that I'm not sure how portable it is, but it's at least part of GNU coreutils.

Comment: According to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tty.html), `tty` may not support the `-s` option. So either use `[ -t N ]`, or redirect output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: And, if you want to check stdout, not stdin, do `tty < /dev/fd/1`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in bash scripts (see the `test expr` entry in `man bash`), it is not necessary to use the beefy `&&` and `||` shell operators to combine two separate runs of the `[` command, because the `[` command has its own built-in *and* `-a` and *or* `-o` operators that let you compose several simpler tests into a single outcome.

So, here is how you can implement the test that you asked for — where you flip into batch mode if *either* the input *or* the output has been redirected away from the TTY — using a single invocation of `[`:

```
if [ -t 0 -a -t 1 ]
then
    echo Interactive mode
else
    echo Batch mode
fi
```

Comment: Shellcheck says `[a] && [b]` is more portable than `[a -a b]`, though.

Comment: (If you're interested in specifics, here's the message it gives: `SC2166: Prefer [ p ] && [ q ] as [ p -a q ] is not well defined.`)

Comment: Note that -a and -o are extensions that are not guaranteed to be present or work alike in all shells or `test` implementations. Even the GNU `test` man page warns against them.

Comment: @bacondropped @ʇsәɹoɈ — As the question is about a bash script, the governing documentation is `man bash` not `man test`, and both `-a` and `-o` are well-specified and fully described. Your comments are useful, though, for anyone who lands on this question but is writing for a non-bash shell and does not realize the difference! I have edited my answer to make clearer that it is bash-specific, and to refer to the appropriate section of the bash man page.