# How to receive data via stdin without prompting?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, stdin, automator

I'm attempting to write an automator action for macOS that passes in the selected text to a Bash shell script. Automator passes the text to my shell script via `stdIn`

I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myVar=$(</dev/stdin)
echo "$myVar"
```

and:

```
read -t 1 input
echo "$input"
exit 0
```

While first above example works, if I run the script directly on the command-line it waits for input. In the second example it will stop waiting after one second but I only get the text up to the newline.

I don't want the script to wait for input on the command line but I do want it to accept input from other programs i.e. Automator which passes in the text via stdIn.

It would also be nice if the script accepted input via pipe e.g. :

```
cat myfile | ./myscript
```

What I'm trying to achieve is optionally take stdIn if there is something passed but I never want to prompt the user for input on the command-line.

> Essentially the input is optional in my program.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022323/check-isatty-in-bash <-- this answer definitely works on macos, so you could detect interactive mode and act appropriately (such as reading stdin to eof in the non interactive case).

Comment: @ArtYerkes Thanks, the solution linked seems to work nicely.