# read loop from <(git log --oneline) has different output from "git log --oneline" at terminal

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, parentheses

I'm encountering a weird problem. I'm trying to parse the output of a git command. When I run the git command from the command line, it works as expected:

```
$ git log --oneline 32004f
32004f9 (tag: This_is_a_tag,_too, tag: Tag_from_command_line, origin/Project_A, Project_A) Merged
65f6f61 More changes
925f619 (tag: This_is_a_tag) Pulled from remote
(etc.)
```

But as soon as I try to redirect or pipe the output, anything inside parentheses disappears:

```
$ while read -r ; do echo $REPLY; done < <(git log --oneline 32004f)
32004f9 Merged
65f6f61 More changes
925f619 Pulled from remote
```

*[Edit: Note that the echo command is used strictly to illustrate the problem. The actual script will split the results into multiple variables for parsing and processing]*

```
$ git log --oneline 32004f | hexdump -C | head
00000000  33 32 30 30 34 66 39 20  4d 65 72 67 65 64 0a 36  |32004f9 Merged.6|
00000010  35 66 36 66 36 31 20 4d  6f 72 65 20 63 68 61 6e  |5f6f61 More chan|
00000020  67 65 73 0a 39 32 35 66  36 31 39 20 50 75 6c 6c  |ges.925f619 Pull|
00000030  65 64 20 66 72 6f 6d 20  72 65 6d 6f 74 65 0a 64  |ed from remote.d|
```

But a quick shell script that I whipped up echoes parentheses works fine:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "32004f9  (HEAD -> Project_A, tag: This_is_a_tag,_too, tag: Tag_from_command_line, origin /Project_A) Merged"

$ while read -r ; do echo $REPLY; done < <(./test.sh)
32004f9 (HEAD -> Project_A, tag: This_is_a_tag,_too, tag: Tag_from_command_line, origin /Project_A) Merged
```

I'm stumped. Can anyone help me with this?

Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
git version: git version 2.15.0

Comment: `echo $REPLY` creates a bunch of extra bugs. Always quote: `echo "$REPLY"`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: that said, to see if you have behavior differing on whether output is to a TTY, just pipe to `cat`: If `foo | cat` differs from `foo` in the same way you're investigating, you know it's `isatty()`-based behavior, as randomir's answer indicates.

Comment: (btw, "fails" isn't a very descriptive word, in the context of a site where almost *every* question is about something behaving in a manner other than intended; I've tried to edit to make the title more specific to the individual question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `--decorate` option for `git log`:

> `--no-decorate, --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]`
>
> Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If `short` is specified, the ref name prefixes `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/` and `refs/remotes/` will not be printed. If `full` is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed. If **`auto` is specified, then if the output is going to a terminal, the ref names are shown as if short were given, otherwise no ref names are shown**. The default option is `short`.

Looks like you have `--decorate=auto` set somewhere in your git config.

To force ref names (including tags), simply specify:

```
git log --oneline 32004f --decorate=short
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have never before encountered a program whose output is different depending on whether it's going to the terminal or being piped/redirected. 

That's going to have a significant impact on the way I write Bash scripts - I always use the command line to prototype the command, then copy-and-paste it into my script (sometimes with varying degrees of frustration getting the number of backslashes right).

Comment: You're welcome. It's easy to miss, but many command line/UNIX tools actually format their output differently when writing to a terminal (TTY), vs. when writing to a file. Usually, ANSI codes (like colors) are omitted when writing to a file -- `ls`, `grep`, `git show/diff/log` all do this by default. Many have an option to control it (`--color` or similar) -- try: `ls --color=always | hd`. As CharlesDuffy noted above, C programs use [`isatty(fd)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to differentiate, and you can use [`[ -t fd ]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10022323) in Bash.