# How to paginate git output only when necessary

Tags: git

Is there a way to configure git to pipe its output into a paper *only when it exceeds the terminal size* (or at least a specific number of lines)? I think it's rather annoying that e.g. a 6-line diff is shown in the pager - hiding any previous output, and requiring me to explicitly press "q" to exit.

Comment: Specify a pager that behaves that way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On most systems, [`less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) is the default pager that Git uses and you can configure less to behave like you describe with:

```
git config --global core.pager "less -X -F"
```

> **-F or --quit-if-one-screen** Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.
>
> **-X or --no-init** Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable
>   if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like
>   clearing the screen.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174327/how-to-automatically-pipe-to-less-if-the-result-is-more-than-a-page-on-my-shell) for more options with configuring less.

Also, specifically with regards to the `diff` command you can use:

```
git --no-pager diff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your pager by setting the `PAGER` variable, and any program which needs a pager will use it. `less` has an option `-F` which does exactly this. Adding `export PAGER="less -F"` to your `~/.bashrc` will make this permanent.

Personally I use `less -FXRS`; see the man page for less for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is the default. Git starts `less`, and if `$LESS` is not set, Git sets it to `FRX` (see `man git-config`).

If you don't see this behavior, then most likely someone (some distros do this by default) have set `$LESS` for you. You can either unset it in your shell's config file, or use one of the other answers.

Comment: This clears  many of my confusion. I've tweaked PAGER, git's config on color, pager etc,  all making me more confusing. Trues out I have LESS set manually, just should add the -FR options to it.