# How to achieve pagination in Git tag

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, git-tag

Anyone Help Me out on

- Limiting git tag to 100
- Need to **fetch first 100 tag on 1st fetch** need to pass some **key or token** to get next batch **like pagination is possible**

Have found some command like

```
git tag
git ls-remote --tags origin
git tag --count=10
```

Please help me out which is the proper way to achieve this

Comment: I guess you have to combine the git tag output with head/tail, awk, or a simple handcrafted bash script.

Comment: No, `git-tag` does not support fetching only part of the tags. You can configure your paginator though (by default is `less`) using the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796075/how-to-paginate-git-output-only-when-necessary

Answer (score 1):

git itself does not provide that feature but you can do:

```
git tag | more
```

or

```
git tag | more -{{lines-to-display-per-page}}
```